# 6 people are holding a show, one at a time, such that person $x$ has to go after person $y$ and person $z$. How many ways could the show be held?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say the people are called $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $y$, $z$

My initial thinking was to go by fixing "$x$" in a certain position, so:

$\underline {} \underline {} \underline {}\underline {}\underline {}\underline {x}$

Now for this configuration we have 5! combinations

$\underline {}\underline {}\underline {}\underline {}\underline {x}\underline {}$

For this one, after the $x$, only $a$, $b$ and $c$ can go, so that's $3 \cdot 4!$.

Similarly, I continued and got an answer in the $300$'s, which is not a possible given answer I have.

What's wrong with my method?

Comment: You may be interested to read about [Linear Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension).  This question is (as mentioned in my answer) equivalent to asking how many different linear extensions exist for this specific poset.  In general, the problem can be somewhat difficult and is P-Complete.  [Here](http://posets.tcs.uj.edu.pl/archive/attachements/DraftChapters/grb-wtt-8.pdf) is a rather wordy paper on the topic, but there should be more elementary examples and explanations in most combinatorics books with sections on Posets.

Comment: Thanks, but that's a pretty extensive topic for me to study when I'm having a test that includes very basic combinatorics like this soon :)

Comment: Indeed.  I was merely trying to provide some information as to the "lack" of an easy "generalized formula" as the general question can be quite difficult.  Take for a somewhat extreme example, 26 people holding a show (labeled a,b,c,d,...) and you know a comes before d,f,g,h and n, and that b comes before f,i,x,y,z and that c comes before b,g,l  etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that *after* is not restricted to *immediately* after.

There are $6!$ ways that the people can be arranged without restriction. There are $3!$ *relative* orders for $x,y,z$. Exactly $2$ of these relative orders have $x$ after $y$ and $z$. So the number of ways is $6!\times \frac{2}{3!}$.

We can do the calculation more slowly. Imagine $6$ chairs in a row. We can choose $3$ of these to put 'Reserved" signs on in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways. We can then choose who of $x$, $y$, $z$ sits at which resereved chair in $2$ ways, for $x$ must sit on the last reserved chair. And then we can arrange the remaining people in the empty chairs in $3!$ ways, for a total of $\binom{6}{3}\times 2\times 3!$.

Comment: Yep, that is the answer. Is there a more generalized formula to this? Why wouldn't my method work?

Comment: Your procedure will work. Calculate separately the ways in which $x$ is in positions $3,4,5,6$.  The idea described in the answer above works smoothly for any number $n$ of people, giving answer $n!\times \frac{2}{3!}$.

Answer (score 3):

We are given a poset $\{a,b,c,x,y,z\}$ where the only comparisons defined are $x>y$ and $x>z$.  We try to find how many ways there are to extend this to a chain.

First: either $x>y>z$ or $x>z>y$.  Two choices.  Without loss of generality, assume it is the first one.

Now, decide where to place $a$ in that list.  Either $a>x>y>z$ or $x>a>y>z$ or $x>y>a>z$ or $x>y>z>a$.  Four choices.

Now, decide where to place $b$ in that list.  Whichever was selected on the previous step, there will be five choices available.

Finally, decide where to place $c$ in that list.  Whichever was selected on the previous step, there will be six choices available.

The total number of ways then is:

$$2\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6 = 240$$

Answer (score 3):

You can make your method work.

If $x$ is in the last position, then there are $5!$ ways to arrange the other letters.

If $x$ is in the fifth position, then there are $3$ ways to select the letter in the last position from among $a, b, c$ and $4!$ ways to arrange the letters before $x$.  Therefore, there are $3 \cdot 4!$ arrangements with $x$ in the fourth position as you found.

If $x$ is in the fourth position, then there are $3$ ways to select the letter in fifth position and two ways to select the letter in the sixth position from among $a, b, c$.  There are $3!$ ways to arrange the letters before $x$.  Thus, there are $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3! = 6 \cdot 3!$ arrangements in which $x$ is in the fourth position.

If $x$ is in the third position, then there are $2!$ ways to arrange $x$ and $y$ in the first two positions and $3!$ ways to arrange $a$, $b$, and $c$ in the last three positions, giving $2! \cdot 3!$ arrangements in which $x$ is in the third position.

Since $y$ and $z$ must precede $x$, $x$ cannot be in the first two positions.  Hence, the number of arrangements in which $x$ follows both $y$ and $z$ is 
$$5! + 3 \cdot 4! + 6 \cdot 3! + 2! \cdot 3! = 240$$
That said, this method is less efficient than those of Andre Nicolas and JMoravitz.

Here is an alternate method:

There are six positions to fill.  We have six ways of placing the $a$, five ways of placing the $b$, and four ways of placing the $c$.  This leaves us with three positions to fill.  We must place the $x$ in the final open position.  There are $2!$ ways to place $y$ and $z$ in the remaining open positions.  Thus, the number of ways the show can be held so that $x$ appears after both $y$ and $z$ is 
$$P(6, 3) \cdot 1 \cdot 2! = 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 240$$

Answer (score 0):

Simply represent as $abc\vee\vee\vee$ where each $\vee$ is a 'slot' where one of $x,y,z$ may be placed, although $x$ and $y$ must occupy the first $2$ slots.  So $a\vee bc\vee \vee$, $a\vee b\vee \vee c$, etc. possibilities. $a,b,c$ remain in same order.  Number of permutations is $P(6,3)={{6!}\over {3!}}$.  However the $\vee$'s cannot be distinguished so must divide by $3!$: $6!\over{3!3!}$ which is actually equal to $6\choose 3$.

Then must multiply by $3!$ for orderings of $a,b,c$ and $2!$ for orderings of $x,y$.

Final answer is $6\choose 3$$2!3!$.